# Stackoverflow's questions list : is sorting needed?

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface, feedback

I was wondering if there will be possibility to **sort** questions list in stackoverflow **by answers number, votes number, date**, or anything else ?

Is there any possibility to specify **ASC** or **DESC** just by clicking ?

Comment: please, could anyone tell me, what's wrong in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already can do this.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes - Votes
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest - Date

There is no way to sort by answer count (that seems pointless) but you can search "answers:*n*" and get questions with *n* or more answers.

Other helpful sorting schemes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured - Bounty expiring in the shortest amount of time
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered - No upvoted answers sorted by votes
- https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week - Popular this week
- https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month - Popular this month

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by date (newest), and by votes already, just click on the big handy tabs.

There is not much use for sorting by answer count, I don't think. You cannot reverse the sort; just click through to the last page of the batch instead, *most* visitors would not need to reverse the sort. What use is the most downvoted question, really?

Comment: Only if you want to find the most non-constructive question on all of SO. =)

Comment: :) not really the most downvoted but maybe the most upvoted and with Zero answers

Comment: @jramby: use the [unanswered tab](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) for that. :-)

Comment: I find the most downvoted questions fascinating and entertaining. Remember "How to iterate over all possible GUIDs?" (now deleted). That was a great read. And the most downvoted meta questions are pretty good as well.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: I don't. Not *most*. Luckily they get cleaned up pretty quickly. The GUID iteration question *was* entertaining, but only because noone could believe the OP was really that thick..